# Setup Groovy AST transformation in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

Setup Groovy AST transformation in gradle

Hi,
I need to run custom Groovy AST transformation that modifies bytecode using gradle groovy plugin. It worked for me when my custom AST transformation classes are imported from external library as mentioned in gradle documentation:

```
configurations { astTransformation }
dependencies {
    astTransformation("org.mymodules:myast:1.0.0"))
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).configureEach { astTransformationClasspath.from(configurations.astTransformation)
}
```

However I need to apply it also on a few classes in the original module where the AST transformation is implemented. I am not able to configure it correctly. I have noticed that original groovy AST transformations like @ToString work at that project as expected (the resulting code is transformed). But the one I have implemented is just ignored.

I have tried something like this (no other gradle.build modifications):

```
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).configureEach {
   astTransformationClasspath.from(sourceSets.main.compileClasspath)
}
```

But from bytecode it is visible that the transformation was not applied.

Any idea how to set it up?

Many thanks,
Lukas

Comment: I don't understand " I have noticed that original groovy AST transformations like @ToString are applied ...". Just to clarify, are you saying that your AST project has code that uses standard annotations like `@ToString` ?

Comment: ToString works on classes in my project as expected. But my custom AST transformations does not work when used on my classes. They are just ignored

Comment: I hope it is understandable. In other words ... I have module Foo where are my transformations implemented. I have module Bar that is using ASTs from Foo and it works. But my transformations does not work with any of classes from module Foo. When I try e.g. ToString transformation in module Foo it works as expected

Comment: @MichaelEaster Maybe it is intended to always sit in separated module .... I don't know ...

Comment: The more I am thinking about that the more it seems to me obvious it actually has to be included in separated module as a dependency because the AST transformation code is is executed at compile time and at that time it is not actually fully compiled yet when it sits in the same module